# How to do a total daily count on database?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would love some help, i am trying to sort some data out, but since i dont have the necessary skill or understanding to carry it out, i am looking for kind support.

I want to get the total daily entries of 'Cardboard' type from column D 'stillage reference' based on column B 'timestamp'

[image]

Comment: Checkout `COUNTIFS` or use a Pivot Table.

Comment: i was after a step by step process

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make a new column (c) with just the day (not full time) using this formula in c2. You can then drag the bottom right hand corner of the cell down so it applies to the entire column.

=date(year(B2),month(B2),day(B2))

Next, add the below formula which assumes column c use the date formula above, e is the stillage reference, and f2 is where the date you would like to count the # of cardboards is.2.

=countifs(C:C,F2,E:E,"CB (Cardboard Coffin & Pallet)")

You can then add additional dates to column f and drag the bottom right hand corner of the formula down to make it apply to additional dates in column f.

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Condensing the attached screen shot column B has DateTime stamp and column G has same dates, therefore for the below show methods I would like to use Dates from column G.*

- For better understanding I've used only few columns.

**Original Data:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select A1:B16.
- From HOME Tab, reach to Editing section.
- Hit Sort command Icon then Custom Sort.
- First select the Date column for Sort By and next add LEVEL and use Stillage references.

*Check the Screen shot:*

[image]

- Finish with Ok.

[image]

**Method 1:**

- Formula in cell C2:

  ```
  =IF(IF(B1<>B2,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$16,"CB",$B$2:$B$16,B2),"")=0,"",IF(B1<>B2,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$16,"CB",$B$2:$B$16,B2),""))
  ```

**Method 2:**

- Array (CSE) Formula in cell E2:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$16,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$B$2:$B$16),0)),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Formula in cell F2:

  ```
  =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$16,E2,$A$2:$A$16,"CB")
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*